# Notepad++ / UltraEdit: Search for id="xyz" and replace xyz

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, ultraedit

I want to build a test scenario and need to search in a `html` document for this:

```
<a id="xyz" href="#"></a>
<a id="123pa" href="#"></a>
<span id="sdasd"></span>
```

I want to replace `id="someString"` with `id=""`

Working with Notepad++ and UltraEdid.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What have you tried? Won't the `id="something"` matches the id? And since you don't need to extract anything, you can just replace with `id=""`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `id=".+?"` or `id="[^"]+"` by `id=""`.